# No implicit conversion between XNode and XElement

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have two variables XResult, Xtemp of type XElement.

I am trying to extract all the `<vehicle>` elements from Xtemp and add them to Xresult under `<vehicles>`.

It seems that in Xtemp sometimes `<vehicle>` will appear under `<vehicles>`, and sometimes it will be by itself.

```
XResult.Descendants(xmlns + "Vehicles").FirstOrDefault().Add(
   XTemp.Descendants(xmlns + "Vehicles").Nodes().Count() > 0 
   ? XTemp.Descendants(xmlns + "Vehicles").Nodes() 
   : (XTemp.Descendants(xmlns + "SearchDataset").FirstOrDefault().Descendants(xmlns + "Vehicle")));
```

In the code above I am using the ternary operator to check if `<vehicles>` has childs then get all of them else go get all  `<vehicle>` elements.

This produces the error: no implict conversion between `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XNode>` and `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable <System.Xml.Linq.XElement>`

Can some body help me correct this.
Thanks in advance.
BB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the ternary you need to decide whether to use `Nodes()` or `Descendants()`. You can't have both. `Nodes()` returns an `IEnumerable<XNode>`, and `Descendants()` returns `IEnumerable<XElement>`. The ternary expressions need to return the same type.

Change:

```
XTemp.Descendants(xmlns + "Vehicles").Nodes()
```

to:

```
XTemp.Descendants(xmlns + "Vehicles").Nodes()
```

Or you could add `Nodes()` to the second expression.

**EDIT:** if I understood your comment correctly you want to select each vehicle's nodes and itself. Try this in place of `Descendants(xmlns + "Vehicle")`:

```
.Descendants(xmlns + "Vehicle")
.SelectMany(d => d.DescendantNodesAndSelf().Take(1))
```

The `Take(1)` will allow you to grab the entire vehicle node and ignore all the other nodes that belong to it since I don't think you wanted those being repeated.

Comment: Thank you. If I add nodes to the second expression  .Descendants(xmlns + "Vehicle").Nodes  then I get all the childs under <vehicle> but I want to extract <vehicle> and its childs.

Comment: @BumbleBee see my edit. If that doesn't answer your question please update your original question to show a short sample of your XML with your code and also show what your expected result should be.